# Сделать динамическое добавление данных в таблицу

Tags: javascript, append, table

Всем привет! Помогите сделать добавление данных с input в таблицу. Данные должны добавляться динамически и сохраняться пока не будет обновлена страничка. Реализовать это нужно только при помощи чистого JS.
Создал функцию, но не уверен что это будет работать.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script >

 function average () {
    this.name = document.querySelector('#baza').value;
    this.petrol = document.querySelector("#petrol").value;
    this.cars = document.querySelector('#cars').value;
    this.aver = petrol/cars;

/*Вот тут пошли проблемки:*/
    var name = document.createElement("th");
    name.append() 




</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id= "average">
Автобаза:
<input name="baza" id="baza"  value=""><br/><br/>
Использовали топлива: 
<input name="petrol" id="petrol"  value=""><br/><br/>
Количество авто:
<input name="cars" id="cars" value=""><br/><br/>

<input type="button" value="Считать" onclick= 'average()'>  
<br/>
</form>

<table style="border: 1px solid black">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Автобаза</th>
        <th>Использовали бензина</th>
        <th>Количество авто</th>
        <th>Средний расход топлива</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td><span id="baza"></span></td>
    <td><span id="petrol"></span></td>
    <td><span id="cars"></span></td>
    <td><span id="aver"></span></td>
</tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Надо без jQuery?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да. Желательно без него, но если это будет не возможно, тогда уже можно подключить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виде сниппета [не работает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4877/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85) из-за настроек безопасности, но вообще всё хорошо.

https://jsfiddle.net/3dyoqgfn/

```js
document.getElementById('average').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var cols = ['baza', 'petrol', 'cars'];
  
  for (var q=0; q<cols.length; ++q) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.textContent = document.getElementById(cols[q]).value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.textContent = "Понятия не имею";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  document.getElementById('dest').appendChild(tr);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<form id="average">
  <label>Автобаза: <input name="baza" id="baza" value=""></label>
  <label>Использовали топлива: <input name="petrol" id="petrol" value=""></label>
  <label>Количество авто: <input name="cars" id="cars" value=""></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Считать">
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Автобаза</th>
      <th>Использовали бензина</th>
      <th>Количество авто</th>
      <th>Средний расход топлива</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dest">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Все равно не хочет добавлять в  таблицу.

Comment: @Nikita, всё хочет и добавляет: https://jsfiddle.net/3dyoqgfn/

Comment: А нет, прости! Моя косяк был! Спасибо тебе огромное за помощь!